# Javascript round a number based on a condition

Tags: javascript

How can i use

```
Math.round()
```

to round an input based on Reminder of 2000

If input is between

1-2000 = 1

2001- 3000 = 1.5

3001-4000  = 2

4001-5000 =2.5

5001-6000 = 3

Example if input is 1500 , then result is 1  ,   if input is 4000 then result is 2 , If input is 40001 then result is 2.5 like that

&

Also need to round another input based on Reminder of 32

If input is between

1-32 =1

33-64 =2

65-96 = 3

Example if input is 31 result is 1 , input =64 result =2 &  input= 95 result 3 etc

Comment: If else or switch case cant be a generic solution . If the  input is in range of 10 thousands how many if else loops i have to maintain?So i am trying to achieve a general solution

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p2ttr1jL/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a round method in this case and a special case for < 2001

```js
function r1(num) {
    if (num <= 2000) {
        return 1;
    }
    return Math.ceil((num - 2000) / 1000) * .5 + 1
}

test(1, 1);
test(1999, 1);
test(2000, 1);
test(2001, 1.5);
test(2500, 1.5);
test(3000, 1.5);
test(3001, 2);



function test(num, result) {
    console.log(num, r1(num), r1(num) == result)
}
```

---

For the second case

```js
function r2(num) {
    return Math.ceil(num / 32)
}

test(1, 1);
test(31, 1);
test(32, 1);
test(33, 2);
test(64, 2);
test(65, 3);
test(97, 4);



function test(num, result) {
    console.log(num, r2(num), r2(num) == result)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, you can use an if statement to get your desired result

```
var new_number = 0;
var input = your number here

if(input >= 1 && input <= 2000){
    new_number = 1;
}else if(input >= 2001 && input <= 3000){
    new_number = 1.5;
}else if(input >= 3001 && input <= 4000){
    new_number = 2;
}
etc etc etc...
```

Then repeat as necessary.

Hope this helps!